# How many domain levels are there?

Tags: tld

`.com`,`.us` are **TLD**,top level domain, and `co.uk` are **SLD**,second level domain.

Are there "third level domain, fourth level domain" and so on?

How many different TLDs and SLDs are out there?

Comment: `co.uk` is in fact **TLD**

Comment: `.co.uk` is not a **TLD**, but `.uk` is a **TLD** and **ccTLD** (country code top level domain). The manager of `.uk` have decided to divide its sub domains into commercial, education etc. But others has not, like `.se` or `.us`. That is up to the owner of the `TLD` to decide how to do.

Answer (score 15):

This link seems to have the most relevant detail  [Wiki - DNS_Label - Domain name formulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_label#Domain_name_formulation)

> The hierarchy of domains descends from
>   right to left; each label to the left
>   specifies a subdivision, or subdomain
>   of the domain to the right. For
>   example: the label example specifies a
>   subdomain of the com domain, and www
>   is a subdomain of example.com. This
>   **tree of subdivisions may consist of
>   127 levels.**
>
> Each **label may contain up to 63
>   characters**. The full domain name may
>   not exceed a **total length of 253
>   characters**. In practice, some domain
>   registries may have shorter limits.

You asked in a comment

> sub1.google.com is also owned by owner
>   of google.com,but that's not the case
>   for news.bbs.co.uk,say it's not owned
>   by owner of co.uk,but bbs.co.uk!

Any owner of a domain may delegate authority to anyone else.  If I was the owner of example.com, I could delegate authority for sub.example.com to you.  Anyone can delegate their subdomains to other organizations.  If you curious about the policies for a particular domain you'll probably need to find the correct contact for that domain.

Answer (score 3):

I just jumped onto my DNS and created this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [41085.org](http://41085.org/heapsofsubs.png))</sub>

That's 29 levels and counting, so I guess as John said, you can just keep going and going and going

Comment: "the full domain name may not exceed a total length of 253 characters" apparently, so assuming a very short top+second (for example is.gd) you could have 126 levels (including the .is and .gd) if each sub division is only a single character.

Comment: That is actually 127, as you have the top level "`.`" too.  The one above is and gd.

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name#Second-level_and_lower_level_domains

Comment: But `sub1.google.com` is essentially `google.com`.While it's not the case for `news.bbs.co.uk`,its domain is `bbs.co.uk`

Comment: sub1.google.com is not essentially google.com, if an A record for abc.com and an A record for sub1.abc.com that are the same then there won't be any difference in the website you visit unless the web server implements host header filtering. It depends where people point their domains to.

Comment: I mean `sub1.google.com` is also owned by owner of `google.com`,but that's not the case for `news.bbs.co.uk`,say it's not owned by owner of `co.uk`,but `bbs.co.uk`!

Comment: Who is the "owner" of a subdomain is decided by the one owning the domain above.  So who owns `sub1.google.com` is decided by `google.com` and who owns `news.bbs.co.uk` is decided by `bbs.co.uk`.  And who owns `uk` is decided by the owner of `.`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a technical limit to the number of levels but to be sure you should consult the RFCs relating to DNS.

An example such as `news.bbs.co.uk`, as you used in a comment, shows four levels already.